# Trying to call a Javascript function within a table but can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-table

I am writing some Javascript and the purpose of the function is to build a table, and call functions and display the results in certain cells. Here is my code so far for the:

```
function buildproduct(prodName, prodID, prodDescription) {
var data = makeHeader()
data += "<TABLE style='width:100%' border=1 cellpadding=10>"
data += "<TR><TD rowspan=3 style='width:30%;text-align:center;verti…
data += "align:middle'>makeID(prodID)"
data += "</TD>"
data += "<TD>makeName(prodName)</TD>"
data += "<TD style='text-align:right'>makeID(prodID)<…
data += "</TR>"
data += "<TR><TD style='text-align:center' colspan=2>Shopping Cart Link Bar"
data += "</TD></TR>"
data += "<TR><TD colspan=2 >makeDescription(prodDescription)</TD></…
data += "</TABLE>"
data += makeFooter()
return document.writeln(data)
document.close()
}
```

I have been trying to call `makeName(prodName)` inside the table inside of the `<TD>`. When I run it I just get `makeName(prodName)` displayed in text, instead of the contents. Please help!

Comment: This does not seem to be a very ideal way to build html content.  It's prone to errors and mistakes.  Is there a particular reason that you are doing it this way?

Comment: It is my partners request to do it this way. I have it all working I just cant figure out how to call functions in between the <TD>.

Answer (score 3):

The way that you have makeName, it is part of the string itself.  Change it to the following:

```
data+="<TD>" + makeName(prodName) + "</TD>";
```

Comment: Thank you ! worked perfect. Just wondering though, why are the +'s necessary ?

Comment: The + acts as a concatenation operator when used with strings.  You're actually using a shortcut when you use "data += ...", which is effectively "data = data + ...".  When I build strings like this, I find it much faster to append to an array and join the array when done, like this: "var data = []; data[data.length] = '<table>'; ...' document.writeln( data.join ( '\n' ) );"

Comment: One other thing: I found that I sometimes had issues creating tables in javascript without the <TBODY> tag.  I doubt it's still an issue (was with IE), but keep that in mind.